# Undefined index while uploading

Tags: php, upload, undefined-index

I have a problem that i just quite do not understand at all. I have this uploading script that always return ***Notice: Undefined index: uploadPDF in xxxxx***

I've made sure that the form has the enctype="multipart/form-data" `<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

The field also has the same name that i ask for in the code `<input name="uploadPDF"  size="100" type="file" title=""/>`

When i try to echo `$_POST['uploadPDF']` i actually get the filename in question. But when i try to var_dump the following `$_FILES['uploadPDF']['name']` i get the undefined index error.

I really cant see what the problems is. I'm running on a inhouse IIS server.

Debug information:

This is the "debug" i try to do:

```
echo $_POST['uploadPDF']."<br />";
$filename = $_FILES['uploadPDF']['name'];
var_dump($filename);
echo "<br />";
var_dump($_FILES);
```

This is the output i get:

```
TEST PDF PORTAL V3.pdf
Notice: Undefined index: uploadPDF in C:\inetpub\myfolder\V4\admin\addRoutine.php on line 29 
NULL 
array(0) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you upload file, you should use 
`$_FILES['file_name']` not `$_POST['file_name']` that is because, the file information is stored in the `$_FILES` arrays, since you have named your input type to 'file'

So, I would suggest

Changing

`echo $_POST['uploadPDF'];`

to

`echo $_FILES['uploadPDF'];`

Comment: The reason i use $_POST in my first debug is to see if the index 'uploadPDF' actually exists, and it does. When i try to do the same only with $_FILE i get the undefined index 'uploadPDF'. So, i verified that the index exists with $_POST, but the $_FILES function wont take it...

Comment: Well, you could just use `if($_POST)` then `var_dump($_POST)` I don't understand your question clearly, you have even wrote `$_FILE` and I don't know what it does

Comment: The problem is that $_FILES['uploadPDF'] returns undefined index, right? So that says me that there is a problem with the form field that i've called uploadPDF, since $_FILED['uploadPDF'] returns undefined index. To check if the form field is wrong i try to echo out the POST information, since this returns a value i know that there is no problem with the form field since i can get the value with POST, but not with FILE.

Comment: @Oleaha Can you post your file upload script so, I can have a look at it?

Answer (score 1):

Your form as you wrote it has no action specified.

```
 ( <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> )
```

You need the asign "path_to_yourform.php" as your form action.

Answer (score 0):

You better write it like this:

```
echo $_POST['uploadPDF']."<br />";
    $filename = $_FILES['uploadPDF']['name'];       
    echo var_dump($filename)."<br />";
```

Comment: It gives the same output and is only there for debug information, not to be rude but i don't understand how this helps me :) I've stripped down the script so i know that the $_FILES wont find the index, but $_POST do...

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is quite embarrassing, one of the other guys working on this had left a `<form action="" method="post">` in one of the included files in the project. Since this form tag was before my form tag $_FILES did not catch the index because of the missing enctype in the first form tag!